# Adding event handler to an iframe using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe, keydown

I want to assign a keydown event handler to an iframe. Something similar to the pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.addEventListener('keydown',funcName, true);
```

I tried:

```
$(document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow).keydown( function() {
   // my func
});
```

But it does not work.. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [keydown event on a iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199075/keydown-event-on-a-iframe)

Answer (score 15):

`contentWindow` is the `iframe`'s `window` object. You want the `iframe`'s `document` instead:

```
$(document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document).keydown(function() {
    // my func
});
```

Note that I am not sure how jQuery reacts to elements from other windows/frames.

Comment: Be wary with this. I believe this will cause a pretty large memory leak where the iframe's content will remain in memory even after you change its URL.

Answer (score 4):

Just something to keep in mind: this will never work, as far as I understand, if the iframe content is cross-domain.  You'll end up with permissions errors: Permission denied for http://... to get property HTMLDocument.nodeType from http://....  Browsers limit parent child dom permissions to same domain.

Answer (score 0):

The $ function replaces the need for document.getElementById

```
$('iframe_id').contentDocument.keydown(function() {
   // logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('#iframe_id').contents().keydown(function() {
    // my func
});
```