# keydown event on a iframe

Tags: jquery

How i can get keydown event on iframe?

Comment: This answer works grate for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324213/listen-for-mouse-click-and-keypress-events-within-iframe/39617876#39617876

Answer (score 21):

You need to access the document of the iframe which is through the ContentWindow object

```
$(document.getElementById('IFrameId').contentWindow.document).keydown(function(){ alert('Key down!'); });
```

Make sure you bind the event **after** the frame has loaded.

Comment: @Aksival Of course, have been racking my brain wondering why this doesn't work for ages now.

Comment: @RedHouse I have updated the answer to clarify that point (I thought that Aksival's comment would have been clear for people to see)

Comment: Here's a way of binding after load document.getElementById('IFrameId').onload = function(){ as above };

Comment: Doesn't work for me. :(

Answer (score 5):

[Adding event handler to an iframe using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549488/adding-event-handler-to-an-iframe-using-jquery)

```
$(document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document).keydown(function() {
    // my func
});
```

Comment: `$("#iframe_id").get(0).contentWindow.document` is equivalent to `$(document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document)`

Answer (score 1):

It's so late to answer but maybe is useful for somebody .
I've same problem,that means I've an `iframe inside a HTML` page in a `same domain`.
Now I need to get the `Esc keyup event`.
however I don't want (or some times I can't) to write any script inside iframe body.
to do it, I use below script to detect what is the parent id of element that selected by clicked on it.

```
 $(window).load(function () {
            jQuery(jQuery('[id="frame"]')[0].contentWindow.document).on('keyup', function (e) {

                var _currntItem = ($(e.target))

                if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                    alert(_currntItem.parent().attr('id'));
                }
            });
```

This code resolved my problem.
hope to useful.