# Listen for mouse click and keypress events within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to add some explanations to each slide of an embedded [swipe.to](http://swipe.to) presentation.
Therefore I am trying to count the times a button within the iframe is pressed or certain keystrokes are done. The goal is to determine on which slide the user is in order to display the appropriate slide explanation.

If the user clicks on the link with id `#next` or presses space bar or right arrow an integer should increment. If the user clicks on the link with id `#previous` or presses left arrow the integer should decrease.

Regarding the mouse click events this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088109) did help me a lot. It works like a charm. However I am still having a hard time getting the keypress events to work.

This is what I have got:

**embedding code**

```
<figure class="swipe">
   <iframe src="https://www.swipe.to/embed/0882x" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</figure>
<style>figure.swipe{display:block;position:relative;padding-bottom:56.25%;height:0;overflow:hidden;}figure.swipe iframe{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;border:none;}</style>
```

**code for determining slide count**

```
<script>
        $('body iframe').load(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $('body iframe').contents().find('#next').bind('click',function(e) {
                    i++;
                    alert(i);
            });

            $('body iframe').contents().bind('keypress',function(e) {
                    if(e.keyCode == 32){
                        i++;
                        alert(i);
                    }
            });

            $('body iframe').contents().bind('keypress',function(e) {
                    if(e.keyCode == 39){
                        i++;
                        alert(i);
                    }
            });

            $('body iframe').contents().find('#previous').bind('click',function(e) {
                    i--;
                    alert(i);
            });

            $('body iframe').contents().bind('keypress',function(e) {
                    if(e.keyCode == 37){
                        i--;
                        alert(i);
                    }
            });


        });
</script>
```

Comment: you can't access iFrame that is on different domain

Comment: But why does it work for clicks on the next/previous buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible this way:

```
//left arrow
$(document.getElementById('frame-id').contentWindow.document).keydown(function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == 37){
                    i--;
                };
});

//right arrow and space bar
$(document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.document).keydown(function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 39){
                    i++;
                };
});
```

This should be embedded within `$('body iframe').load(function(){ }`

Comment: This solution works only if the iframe content is from the same domain.