# Adding event handler to iframe to invoke on keyup

Tags: javascript, ajax

On the webpage I have iframe, in which I display some content.
I want to run a function if any key is pressed inside iframe (iframe is editable).

I can do it using ajax (with scriptmanager on page):

```
Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler(document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document, 'keyup', iframeKeyHandler);
```

But I want to do it without ajax!

**Updated Code:**

```
function Init() {
    document.getElementById('iView').contentWindow.document.designMode = "on";       

     document.getElementById('iView').contentWindow.document.onkeyup = function(event) {
       alert(event);
     }    
 }

<body onload="Init()" >   
<iframe id="iView" style="width: 434px; height:371px" ></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant "do it without using the script manager"?

You can do it this way (use [attactEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx)/[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Init() {
    var _win = document.getElementById("iView").contentWindow;
    var _doc = _win.document;
    _doc.designMode = "on";
    if(_doc.addEventListener) {// if support addEventListener
        _doc.addEventListener("keyup", frameKeyUp, true)
    }
    else { //For IE
        _doc.attachEvent("onkeyup", frameKeyUp);
    }
}
function frameKeyUp(e){
    alert(e.keyCode);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Init()" >   
<iframe id="iView" style="width: 434px; height:371px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Or using jQuery's [event handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) for "[keyup](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keyup)":

```
$('#iframe1').keyup(function(event){
  //... do your stuff here ..
  //use event.keyCode to get the asscoiated key
});
```

More info on keyboard event arg can be found [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) and [here](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx).

Comment: and how  can I found out what key was pressed?

Comment: There must be something that I am doing wrong I get: 'event.keyCode' is null or not an object

Comment: Works for me though. Care to update your post with the updated codes?

Comment: done, also note that I need key event for iframe's contentWindow.document

Comment: @kenny: I've overhauled my codes to fit yours. The `keyup` method do not have a consistent behaviour across browsers and I think using the `attachEvent` (IE) and `addEventListener` (others) will be cleaner. I really recommend using jQuery, here's a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549488/adding-event-handler-to-an-iframe-using-jquery