# `keyup` function not triggering with `iframe` element

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I am getting an `iframe`, in which I am finding an element. I tried to add a `keyup` event with `editable` div, but it's not working...

Here is the code:

```
var iframebody = $(editorid).siblings().find('iframe').contents().find('body');

    var div = $('<div />', 
              {text:textstring, 
                class:'txtMsg mceNonEditable',
                "data-mce-contenteditable":"false",
                css:{'background':'#f2f2f2','margin-bottom':'5px'}});


    var msgDiv = $('<div />', 
                {html:msgText,class:'msgText mceEditable', 
                "data-mce-contenteditable":"true", 
                css:{'margin-bottom':'5px','outline':'0'}})
                .keyup(function(){
                    console.log('keyup'); //not working
                });


    var appender = iframebody.append(div).append(msgDiv);

    console.log(iframebody.find('.mceNonEditable').get(0)); //i am getting the object.

    iframebody.find('.mceNonEditable').on('keyup', function () {
        console.log('hi'); //not working!
    });
```

Can anyone explain why this approach isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery detect change or keyup on body tag within iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614545/jquery-detect-change-or-keyup-on-body-tag-within-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

As per Jquery official site [find description](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is

*Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.*

and [on methods description](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is

*Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.*

As `on` is a event like pressing or releasing etc but `find` is not an event so

```
console.log('hi');
```

is working

I think if you  try something like this

```
 iframebody.find('.mceNonEditable').trigger('keyup',function () {
        console.log('hi'); //not working!
    });
```

then you may get your desired result