# Unable to disable links in iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, click

I want to disable all links inside an iFrame.

The iFrame is actually the preview frame for the markItUp text editor. I have tried the following based on another Stack Overflow answer but it does not work for me:

```
$(".markItUpPreviewFrame a").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    alert("You twat! This is a preview, where do you think you're going?");
    return false;
});
```

Below is a rough outline of the HTML with the `markItUp` iframe:

```
<div id="markItUpMarkItUp" class="markItUp">
<div class="markItUpContainer">
    <div class="markItUpHeader"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <textarea id="markItUp" class="markItUpEditor" name="bodyText""></textarea>
    <div class="markItUpFooter"></div>
    <iframe class="markItUpPreviewFrame">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                links in here...
            <body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

When I click on the link, it seems to ignore my jQuery code (I do not get the alert) and loads the page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the click handler to the document in the iFrame, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549488/adding-event-handler-to-an-iframe-using-jquery) has an answer that shows how to do that (the last answer)

Comment: I tried the following, though it is still the same result:
`$(document.getElementById('markItUpPreviewFrame').contentWindow.document).live('click', function(e) { ..prevent stuff in here });`

note: i also added the id 'markItUpPreviewFrame' to the iframe..

Comment: Could it be because the iframe is not added until later (after the preview button is pressed)?.. So that when the above code is executed, the markItUpPreviewFrame does not exist...

Comment: The live() method should cater for that, although it is recommended to use the on() method now for all event handling. Try Sthe's solution above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        //Make sure the iframe is done loading before you attach an event
        $(".markItUpPreviewFrame").load(function(){
            // Get the body element
            var frameBody = $(".markItUpPreviewFrame").contents().find("body");

            // Get all links inside the BODY tag
            $('a', frameBody).click(function(e){
                    //Disable all default actions       
                    e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, i gave it a shot but it doesn't work. I added an `alert("hi");` after the `$(".markItUpPreviewFrame").load(function(){` line and it did not get executed. I pressed the preview button, and nyet. The iframe displayed as normal and the links are still clickable.

Comment: Do you load your iframe dynamically? (in case I might have missed that). You could replace `$(".markItUpPreviewFrame").load(function(){` with `$(".markItUpPreviewFrame").live('load', function(){`. I tested this example and it worked for me.

Maybe just check the Error Console as well and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Yeah i do load it dynamically. That didn't work either. I do get an error in the Error Console and that is `$ is not defined <html>` but i'm not sure that it is related. Very bizarre because the code you provide looks like it should work!

Comment: It sounds very related to me, because if `$` id not defined, you can never be able to use jQuery at all. Does any of your jquery code work? On that page that is?

If it doesn't, try rewriting the `<script src=""..` tag to make sure that it can find your jquery library.

If this doesn't work check if you didn't run: `jQuery.noConflict()` anywhere on your page.

Comment: Which page do you mean? The parent, or the page in the the iframe? Because jQuery is working and doing a bunch of stuff already in the parent (the page containing the iframe). There are no scripts in the page that is within the iframe.

Comment: If you have the above code on an external javascript file, just make sure you only include it AFTER including the jQuery library like so:

`<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ...` THEN `<script src="my-js-file.js" type="text/javascript" ...`

Comment: did a search for `noConflict()` and it doesn't appear anywhere (other than in the jquery library itself). My external js file (containing code above) comes after jquery, like you say.

Comment: If your other jQuery code works on the parent page, then there is only one response I have: "`I have no idea why it doesn't work. Sorry I couldn't help`"