# Detecting clicks on an embedded webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an embedded web page on a website (Example: www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar). The user than clicks on a hyperlink inside the article (Ex:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasolar_planet).

I want to have a frame which displays the name of the article (in this case, "Extrasolar planet") when the user clicks an entry from the original article ("Pulsar")

How do I know what the user has clicked?

EDIT: After seeing many examples, I tried to do this instead, but it doesn't quite work.

```
<iframe width="940" height="550" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random">    </iframe>


<script>
(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').contentWindow.document).keydown = function() {
alert("Hello World")
})
</script>
```

Comment: You can attach event-listeners in an iframe like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/550247/2171046).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doens't work because you're using `getElementsByTagName` which returns an array. Use `getElementById` or `getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]` instead.

Comment: I'm expecting an alert when the user clicks something inside the embedded website, but I don't get that.

Answer (score 0):

`contentWindow` is the `iframe`'s `window` object. Here you want the `iframe`'s `document`:

```
$(document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document).keydown(function() {
    // my func
});
```

OR

```
  $(document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow.document).click(function() {
        // my func
    });
```

Comment: This is in Javascript right? I have embedded the web page with HTML object code.

Comment: Yes this is javascript. You need javascript to detect clicks. Right? HTML can never do that. I couldn't understand what you asked in your comment.